Are these comparison morphisms between Čech and Grothendieck cohomology the same?
For better or for worse, there is more than one approach to comparing Čech cohomology $\smash{\check{H}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})$ of a sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on a space $X$ w.r.t the cover $\mathfrak{U}$ with $\mathscr{F}$'s Grothendieck/derived sheaf cohomology $\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})$. TlDr; my question is whether these comparisons are the same. We speak of "the canonical map" but I'm not sure if this term is justified, since I can see three potentially distinct candidates for the "canonical" one.
I've also recently suspected that Godement's proof that "the" comparison map preserves cup products is subtly incorrect. I could give an alternative correct one… if all the comparison maps really are the same! From a computational perspective this makes me care even more about this.
Well - it's not exactly incorrect, but it's missing details and in any case I encounter a new problem; for similar reasons (derived functor nonsense versus explicit spectral sequences) it is wholly unclear whether or not Godement's definition of the sheafy cross product is the same as Iversen's. I may ask that as a new question.

In Godement's book "Topologie algébrique et théorie des faisceaux" a few are discussed and they show the comparison homomorphisms $\smash{\check{H}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})$ you obtain from the different methods are the same. Let me call this homomorphism $(1)$ (for those without the book, one way to get it is by taking the sheafy Čech resolution of $\mathscr{F}$ and then taking the double complex with columns the Godement resolutions of each of the sheaves $\mathfrak{C}^k(\mathfrak{U};\mathscr{F})$ and then using edge homomorphisms in a spectral sequence; alternatively first take an injective/Godement resolution of $\mathscr{F}$ then make a double complex by taking Čech resolutions in the columns).
However there is another pair of comparison homomorphisms which both seem suitable for manual and theoretical computations. We can check, for a fixed commutative ring $k$, that the classical right derived functors of $\smash{\check{H}}^0(\mathfrak{U},X;-):\mathsf{Psh}(X;k)\to k\mathsf{Mod}$ are uniquely isomorphic with $\smash{\check{H}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},X;-)$ as defined by the usual cosimplicial complex, by the effaceability theorem of Grothendieck. Then, denoting by $\iota$ the subcategory inclusion $\mathsf{Sh}(X;k)\to\mathsf{Psh}(X;k)$, it is obvious that $\smash{\check{H}}^0(\mathfrak{U},X;-)\circ\iota=\Gamma$ the usual global sections functor and $\iota$ preserves injective objects so there is a canonical strongly convergent Grothendieck spectral sequence (obtained via a Cartan–Eilenberg resolution method): $$E_2^{pq}\cong\smash{\check{H}}^p(\mathfrak{U},X;\underline{\mathscr{H}^q}(\mathscr{F}))\Rightarrow\mathcal{H}^{p+q}(X;\mathscr{F})$$as is well known. Then there are edge homomorphisms $\smash{\check{H}}^n(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\mathcal{H}^n(X;\mathscr{F})$. Let me call this homomorphism $(2)$. A spectral sequence with terms and abutment isomorphic to these can be obtained in very many ways, Godement covers a few which yield homomorphism $(1)$. That does not mean $(1)=(2)$ though, since different models for Čech cohomology are being used: the standard Cech complex and friends on one hand, and the abstract effacement theorem's implication that $\check{H^\bullet}=R^\bullet\check{H^0}$. At any rate I like this approach as it falls out of a generality.
Now by far the easiest homomorphism to dream up is homomorphism $(3)$. We can note $\mathscr{F}\hookrightarrow\mathfrak{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U};\mathscr{F})$ is a pointwise homotopy equivalence, in particular a resolution of $\mathscr{F}$ in the category of sheaves. If $\mathscr{F}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{J}^\bullet$ is an injective resolution (among sheaves) we know there is a well-defined up to homotopy map $\mathfrak{C}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U};\mathscr{F})\to\mathcal{J}^\bullet$ lying over $\mathscr{F}$. We can take global sections and then take cohomology of this map to find homomorphism $(3)$ $\smash{\check{H}}^\bullet(\mathfrak{U},X;\mathscr{F})\to\mathcal{H}^\bullet(X;\mathscr{F})$.
Not for a lack of trying, but I cannot figure out how to prove homomorphisms $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ are identifiably equal once all isomorphisms are accounted for (e.g. one must balance $\smash{\check{H}}^\bullet$ as modelled via the Čech resolution versus the derived functor definition to compare $(2)$ with any of the others). I don't know if that's true, but it obviously should be true. It would be weird if we had more than one distinct comparison map. $(3)$ is simplest but $(2)$ is theoretically most useful; a shame, if they differ. Are these maps all "the same"?
One major obstruction is that Čech cohomology is not a $\delta$-functor when restricted to sheaves; all these maps are natural in the sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ but they are not sensibly homomorphisms of $\delta$-functors so I cannot use any uniqueness theorems along those lines. Short of explicitly resolving everything "by hand", which appears also intractable, I don't know what slick homological-algebraic tricks are available to handle this.

Interesting point! I myself am only a homological amateur, and I only know one proof of the comparison... but, yes, it would be weird... :)

The stuff about double complexes and taking resolutions in two different directions is a hint that this is really a story about $\textbf{R}\textrm{Hom} (k [0], F [0])$ where $k [0]$ is the presheaf chain complex with the constant presheaf $k$ in degree 0 (and $0$ everywhere else) and likewise $F [0]$ is the (pre)sheaf chain complex with $F$ in degree 0. To compute $\textbf{R}\textrm{Hom}$ you can resolve either the left or right variable, or both at once – that's where the spectral sequence comes from. The tricky thing defining quasi-isomorphisms correctly so that you can work with presheaves.
